# How to preserve subdomain during OAuth flow with NodeJS + Passport?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have many sub-domains and need to preserve the correct sub-domain for the authentication request. My OAuth provider allows me to add a custom field 'state' to the authorize which I get back in the response to my callback function.

I need to set the 'state' parameter to the sub-domain from the referrer header in the original request. However, I do not have access to the request object in the code below. How do I make the value of state parameter dynamic based on request headers?

```
appSecure.get('/oauth/authorize', passport.authenticate('forcedotcom', { state: 'test' }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the passport call:

```
function dynamicStateAuth(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('forcedotcom', { state: req.foo })(req, res, next)
}

appSecure.get('/oauth/authorize', dynamicStateAuth);
```